# Neo performance (large page)

Tags: matrix, performance, plugin-neo, speed

I'm using Matrix and Neo to build out quite large, complex entries.
On larger pages (70+ blocks each with one-multiple sub-blocks) the performance is taking a bit of a hit taking upwards of 40 seconds to load (locally running PHP7).

Any thoughts on speeding this up at all, eg selectively loading/collapsing blocks as required rather than load in everything onto the page?

Thoughts/suggestions appreciated,

Cole

Comment: To clarify this concerns page load in the back-end/control panel.
There are no issues with loading in the front-end

Comment: I think you're looking at improving server performance, if it's the backend.

Comment: Thanks @ClivePortman - even locally using Nginx/Apache/PHP7 on pretty high spec MacBook Pro is churning along. Could throw extra resources at it but would rather work out a way to minimise the bottleneck

Comment: Afaik there is no way to speed up the backend itself. I've experienced similar and ended-up working on a remote server (which incidentally had a lot less than power than my SP4).